# Temporarily deactivate constraints for updating datatype of PKs and FKs

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have to update all columns of type "uuid" to "varchar(38)". I created all the necessary queries with:

```
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I SET DATA TYPE varchar(38);',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'uuid'
  AND table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
  AND lower(table_schema) <> 'information_schema'
  AND is_updatable = 'YES';
```

Obviously, I can't execute the resulting queries because of all the existing PK and FK constraints involving the uuid columns.
Is there a way to temporarily disable the constraints, then executing all the queries and reactivating the constraints afterwards without dropping the constraints?
Or if I have to drop all the constraints first, is there a way to set them all up again after the updates? I am not the creator of the database so I don't have all necessary queries to create the constraints again.

Comment: if constraints are not deferrable, you cant "pause" them - have to either order up actions or drop/recreate them. btw if you are not the owner of constraint, you wont be able to drop it. unless you are superuser, but if you are superuser you can do anything, so "don't have all necessary queries to create the constraints again" would not be the case - right?..

Comment: yeah, i'm a superuser... is there a way to build a query in a somehow automated way which sets up all the currently active constraints? this would be worth opening up another question then i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to create all queries for dropping and creating all constraints of the database.
So first I have to save the output of the first query

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" DROP CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'";'
 FROM pg_constraint 
 INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid 
 INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN contype='f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,contype,nspname,relname,conname;
```

and of the second query

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" ADD CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'" "'||
   pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid)||'";'
 FROM pg_constraint
 INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid
 INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN contype='f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC,contype DESC,nspname DESC,relname DESC,conname DESC;
```

When I have all the queries, I first dropped every constrained, updated the tables and then executed the queries for adding the constraints again. Worked perfectly!